# starting google earth with kml file

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch Google Earth 6.1 from my Android app with a specific KML file.  Here is what I have:

```
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "master.kml");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
            startActivity(intent);
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidscope"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

However, when I run I get an ActivityNotFoundException:

> 09-27 14:23:05.290: W/dalvikvm(3525): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400dc760)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/master.kml typ=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml }
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1382)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3095)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3201)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at com.example.androidscope.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:85)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3122)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11942)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>   09-27 14:23:05.290: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I've noticed that if I add:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.earth", "com.google.earth.EarthActivity");
```

then Google Earth loads but with no of the KML information.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Uri earthURI = Uri.fromFile(kmlFile);

Intent earthIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, earthURI);

startActivity(earthIntent);

Answer (score 0):

> Intent earthIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, earthURI);

This seems to work fine on Android 5

Is there an Android 6 permissions change that breaks this intent?